# mongodb query object inside an array

Tags: mongodb

So I have a collection called Transaction that is structured like the following

```
  {
        "_id": "1",
        "type": "purchase",
        "amount": 11.8,
        "relatedObjects": [
            {
                "eventId": "123131313131322"
            }
        ],
       "paymentMethod" : "method1"
    }
```

I want to query according to paymentMethod and eventId. So I was doing the following but it is not working.

```
db.Transaction.find({ "paymentMethod": "method1"});
```

and this is how I go all the transactions for "method1" but I am not sure on how should I query for eventId inside of related objects. I tried something like

```
db.Transaction.find({"paymentMethod": "method1", "relatedObjects[0].eventId" : "123131313131322" })
```

I didnt seem like it was going to work in my head but I have no clue on how to query an object inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

Damn I had to read for third time the docs, sorry,
It was something like

```
{
        "paymentMethod": "method1", 
        "relatedObjects" : {
            $elemMatch : {
                "eventId": "13213213212131321321"
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: A little simpler to use `"relatedObjects.eventId": "13213213212131321321"`